# Getting Voting Responses according to the different mails sent which have same subject

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

```
Sub ExportVotingStatistics_Excel()
    Dim objRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim objVoteDictionary As Object
    Dim varVotingCounts As Variant
    Dim varVotingOptions As Variant
    Dim varVotingOption As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim nRow As Integer
    Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant

Set olMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNameSpace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Folder = OutlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


    'Fill in the predefined values
    Worksheets("Mail-Extraction").Activate
    With ActiveSheet
         .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
         .Cells(1, 1) = "Voting Results for Email:"
         .Cells(1, 2) = "Company follow-up with client"
         .Cells(3, 1) = "Voting Options"
         .Cells(3, 2) = "Voting Recepient"
    End With
Set objVoteDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'get the default voting options
varVotingOptions = Split(olMail.VotingOptions, ";")
'Add the voting responses to the dictionary
For Each varVotingOption In varVotingOptions
    objVoteDictionary.Add varVotingOption, 0
Next
'Add a custom voting response - "No Reply"
objVoteDictionary.Add "No Reply", 0

'Process all the voting responses
For Each olMailRecepient In olMail.Recipients
    If olMailRecepient.TrackingStatus = olTrackingReplied And olMail.Subject = "3rd follow-up with Sales Team Member" Then
'For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
'    If OutlookMail.Subject = "3rd follow-up with Sales Team Member" And OutlookMail.ReceivedTime = #2/17/2020# Then
        If objVoteDictionary.Exists(olMailRecepient.AutoResponse) Then
            objVoteDictionary.Item(olMailRecepient.AutoResponse) = objVoteDictionary.Item(olMailRecipient.AutoResponse) + 1
        Else
            objVoteDictionary.Add olMailRecepient.AutoResponse, 1
        End If
    End If
Next
'Get the voting options and Vote counts
varVotingOptions = objVoteDictionary.Keys
varVotingCounts = objVoteDictionary.Items

'Fill in the values in specific cells
    nRow = 4
    For i = LBound(varVotingOptions) To UBound(varVotingOptions)
        With ActiveSheet
             .Cells(nRow, 1) = olMail.VotingResponse
             .Cells(nRow, 2) = olMail.SenderName
        End With
        nRow = nRow + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

The above code just gives the voting response for the mail that I have currently selected and not the entire mail directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary that you show either what you have tried so far to fix your issue and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. You cannot expect us to write that code for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: The above code is what I have tried so far

Comment: But there is no question in your post that we can answer. You cannot just post your requirements and wait for us to work and fix it. You need to ask a question to your code. You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Consider `Option Explicit`  mandatory.  Add it to the top of existing modules. **Declare the missing variable and fix typos.** To generate `Option Explicit` automatically - Tools | Options | Editor tab then Require Variable Declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, of course, your code only works with the currently selected message returned by `Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection`.

Add a loop over the Inbox items:

```
dim item As Object
...
for each item in Folder.Items
  if item.Class = 43 Then
    set olMail  = item
    For Each olMailRecepient In olMail.Recipients
      ...
    next
  End If
next
```